# selecting one item with two conditions and retrieving in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to retrieve the 2 items that i selected and put it in a label.
Here's my code.

```
     With lCommand
            .Connection = connection
            .CommandText = "select pass from officememberprofile where usern = 'CSProfile1' or usern = 'CSProfile2'"
            lReader = .ExecuteReader
        End With
        With lReader
            While .Read
                Label4.Text = .Item(0)
                Label5.Text = .Item(1)
            End While
        End With
```

-expected result: label4.text should contain CSPass1 and label5.text should contain CSPass2, but the the end result is wrong. It is just retrieving the first item. Can someone show me how to properly use the while loop and retrieve the 2 items in its respective labels. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time this while runs, it gets a row of the result. your result has one column. so you can store it in a stack and then you extract them into labels

```
With lCommand
    .Connection = connection
    .CommandText = "select pass from officememberprofile where usern = 'CSProfile1' or usern = 'CSProfile2'"
        lReader = .ExecuteReader
End With

Dim x As New Stack(Of String)

With lReader
    While .Read
        x.Push(.Item(0))
    End While
End With

Label4.Text = x.Pop()
Label5.Text = x.Pop()
```